# Is HTML too much text for fast web?

Tags: html, network-efficiency

Does anyone know anything about the efficiency of HTML as a transmitted markup language? It seems to me that having closing tags rather than merely a closing curly brace (or just `</>`) adds a lot of text to a file. Bandwidth is a valuable resource, and when billions (trillions?) of HTML files are continually being transmitted around the world, those closing tags add up.

My question is whether they add up enough to make a serious difference. With a briefer closing tag, would there be a noticeable increase in the speed of page loads?

Comment: I made a simple test. I got a random page and extracted all not useful closing tags and I got that about 4% is wasted text. Obviously just analysing an html page without embedded media. even just a 1% trough all web users means tons of money and energy very wasted for all.  I can not believe we are going to cloud computing and software as a service age with this crap of technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your point is valid, but compared to rich media such as audio, video, and images, the "wasted space" is negligible.

HTML, being a markup language, is verbose; but if you take away some of that verbosity, it will suddenly become much more difficult to work with.

Answer (score 11):

No.

If you want smaller download sizes, configure your web-server automatically to `gzip`-compress all `text/html` responses.

Answer (score 2):

No. Relative to images (and video!) HTML is still tiny. Throw in compression and it becomes more so (especially as repeated strings (such as tag names) compress well.

The increase in maintenance costs would more than offset the bandwidth savings.

Comment: I completely agree, though I would point out that JSON is replacing XML, which is analogous to what Cap is suggesting.

Comment: JSON is replacing XML for *some* things, and the reasons for it have little to do with the size. JSON (unlike XML) is very specific about the basic data type of a bit of data (so a generic parser can tell the difference between, for example, an array of data with one item in it and a single items) and it can be easily parsed very quickly in JavaScript. XML still has advantages (namespaces, semantics, etc) and is better for some tasks.

Answer (score 2):

HTML is not efficient, and every indication suggests it will become less efficient.

Take a look at the following example:

```
<b>some bold text</b>
```

vs

```
<span class="boldText">some bold text</span>
.boldText {font-weight:bold;}
```

Ok - its a small example, but it does illustrate my point.

Back in the days of 56k modems, I used to write Javascript functions client side, and then used Ajax (before it was called ajax) to pass down just the values (not the description) and then use the client side to build up elements in the DOM, this proved about 20% more efficient, but left me thinking if anyone would invent HTML shorthand. No one did, and instead we've just upgraded our connections, and you're right - we're throwing around tons of bits, that don't need to be there.

But who cares?

Answer (score 1):

In general, HTML markup is not the limiting factor as far as bandwidth is concerned. Two main reasons:

1. HTML is text, which means it is highly compressible using [HTTP compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).
2. The bandwidth used by HTML is extremely small compared to the bandwidth used by graphics/video.

Answer (score 0):

While technically the closing tags adds a certain percentage to the file size of HTML, it is still infinitesimally small in the grand scheme of all the data flying around the web.

If you are really concerned about it, you can always set up your web-sever to apply compression to html content when it is being served.

Answer (score 0):

Google omits the closing tags on its web pages, but after compression the savings is minimal.  Most people prefer to conform to standards and be able to validate their pages.

http://code.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-html.html

Comment: Did you read that article? If you omit something that is **optional** then you **do** conform to standards.

Comment: @David I meant conform to XHTML as opposed to HTML, but I wasn't clear.